# Convert KAP files

Tags: convert, file-formats

I've got some .KAP files which are missing spatial data and as such, I cannot convert them into something more useful like a .TIF image. I've been using FME which errors on these files with "Failed to specify the feature index as constraints on the reader". Has anyone come across this and found a solution? At this point, i'm happy just to convert to a non-spatial image format.